# What is NSCI in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, dns, connectivity

I am making a local web app. Users will connect through WiFi and all DNS requests result IP of my server. Windows PCs and phones check http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt for check internet connectivity. So I made a simple text file with that name and they think it is OK. 
I have problem with Android and iOS smartphones. Specially iOS, It disconnect WiFi if user ignores its alert.
I think android phones connect to mtalk.google.com:5228 to check notifications and other things.
How can i fool them?

Comment: Why would you need to fool them into believing there's an Internet connection?

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I don't want to OS open sign in page after connecting to WiFi.

Comment: And iOS users mixing up when it disconnects from WiFi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Basically, it’s the Network connectivity status indicator (NCSI) service that does the trick..."
You can see at: http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-windows-7-knows-my-network-connection-status

Comment: I have problem in Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Android has used two different equivalents to Windows' `msftncsi`:

- `clients3.google.com/generate_204` used around Android Kitkat (4.4)
- `connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204` used around Android Marshmallow (6.0)

I'm not sure if iOS uses a similar technique at all...